# How do I fix the broken land around my Falkreath home?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

The plot of land for my Falkreath house is broken. The drafting table and carpenter's workbench are buried and parts of my house are floating. How do I fix it?

Edit: The land is broken around all 3 plots. Are there any mods that mess it up? The picture might look different from yours because I am using the Seasons of Skyrim Summer edition mod and Sexy City Textures.

[image: This is a picture of The Pale property]

This is a picture of the property for The Pale. They're all like this, but the Falkreath and Hjaalmarch properties' Workbench and Drafting table are buried. I deleted all terrain mods and I heard animal mods can mess it up, but I don't have any. The only mods under the Enviromental category is Fire and Ice Overhaul and Lush Trees and Grass.

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: I am playing on PC.

Comment: What mods do you have installed?

Comment: I have a lot. What mods would do stuff like this? I have no landscape changing mods.

Comment: Any texture mods?

Comment: Yes. I have Skyrim 2K textures, Seasons of Skyrim  Summer Edition, and all of the Sexy City textures

Comment: @TheLastPuma does the issue persist without any mods enabled - mods that effect the environment (in anyway) might have had a clash with another mod etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a 2.0.1 patch for Seasons of Skyrim that fixes this issue.

- Go to: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/46628
- Click Files.
- Scroll down to the listing for 2.0.1 and download it
- Install through NMM, or whatever. I'm going to assume you know how to do this part since you wouldn't have this problem without installing a mod to begin with.